# Operand Alternatives in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Inherited a side website of my organization until we are able to find a Web Developer. Initially had to transition the entire PHP website to PDO from MySQL_ statements. After doing my homework I've been mostly successful with that, but now some of the "mechanisms" so to speak are malfunctioning. The one below is one such instance. I understand that the array()/4 is an illegal operation, but I can't find an alternative way to accomplish this function. It could be a learning gap on my part, but I'm also guessing this function wasn't really used the way it was designed to be. Any comments would be appreciated, Thank you.

```
$result = $dbh->query($category);
if  ($dbh = $result->rowCount(1)){
    $cols=4;
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows = $rows/$cols;
    $extrarows=$cols-$rows;
    $extrarows=substr($extrarows,0,1);
    for ($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++) { 
        echo ("<tr>");
        for ($j=0; $j<$cols;$j++){
            //$rowdata=mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $rowdata = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo ("<td valign=\"top\" align=\"center\" width=\"20%\">\n");
            if ($rowdata!=""){
```

Additional Information:

```
if ($e!=""){
    $page="SELECT galleryid from gallery where (year='$year' and event='$e') order by sortorder ASC;";
}elseif ($k!=""){
    $page="SELECT galleryid from gallery where (year='$year' and keyword='$k') order by sortorder ASC;";
}else{
    $page="SELECT galleryid from gallery where year='$year' order by sortorder ASC;";
}
$resultnext = $dbh->query($page);

$array=array();
while($rownext = $resultnext->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $newid=$rownext["galleryid"];
    $image=$rownext["imagetitle"];
    array_push($array,$newid);
}
$id=$_GET['id'];
$key=array_search($id,$array);
$first=array_slice($array,0,1);
$first=$first[0];

$last=array_slice($array,-1,1);
$last=$last[0];

$previous=array_slice($array,$key-1,1);
$previous=$previous[0];

$current=array_slice($array,$key,1);
$current=$current[0];

$next=array_slice($array,$key+1,1);
$next=$next[0];
```

Comment: You still need to unpack one of the array entries from whatever `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returned; `$rows["count"]` or else. What's it supposed to calculate there?

Comment: All in all, its code that initially took a lot of photos in a gallery and displayed them in a series of rows. I'll post some of the relevant additional lines below my original post.

Comment: `$rows` will be a SINGLE row of data. you need `$result->rowCount()` to get the number of rows in the entire result set.

Comment: or you could do `$rows = count($rows) / $cols;`

Comment: @mario Code has been updated to show relevant sections.

Comment: Maybe you should just rewrite it all. If it's just meant to output a grid of images, then `foreach (array_chunk($result->fetchAll(), 4) as $four_rows) {` could perhaps do already. Also wrap some things into functions. Else this won't be maintainable still.

Comment: @JamesSpence I used your solution and it worked, but unfortunately now I'm receiving an undefined offset error in relation to some of the echoed arrays below.  `echo ("<a href=\"images/".$rowdata[2]."_lg.jpg\" rel=\"lightbox[".$e."]\" title=\"".$rowdata[10]."\"><img src=\"images/".$rowdata[2]."_sm.jpg\" width=\"".$rowdata[5]."\" height=\"".$rowdata[6]."\" alt=\"".$rowdata[2]."\" class=\"thumbnail\"/></a>\n");`

Comment: @JaredAquaReece which offset is undefined? One of those indices (2,5,6,10) is not set. Check your data and see what it's returning.

Comment: @JamesSpence Sorry, its specifically indicating 2 in this instance.

Comment: Then $rowdata[2] is not set. Check $rowData, see what it is, and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @JamesSpence Figured it out and posted an answer, thanks for the help =)

Comment: @mario Figured it out and posted an answer, thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change my PDO statement a bit for each $result -> fetch. I  had the initial part correct, but needed to leave out the FETCH_ASSOC. Example below:

`$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

too

`$rows = $result->fetch()`